# msbuild.exe won't deliver the new output after file changed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, solution

Recently I am facing a problem with msbuild.exe by building a dll. My idea is to call the msbuild from DOS command line to automatically create the DLL without opening MS Visual Studio. The command line (as example) I am using is:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe C:\example.sln  /p:Configuration=example_config
```

The problem is, even I changed the files in this project (outside of MS Visual Studio), it seems that msbuild.exe isn't able to recognize the change and still output the old dll based on the old files.

Also I tried to delete the output DLL beforehand, but still the same result. The command line from DOS delivered the old dll.

If I open Visual Studio and build the output manually, the problem won't happen.

I checked around in web but can't find a feasible solution for this. Someone mentioned that it could be problem of MS. Actually, I was also not facing this problem under Windows XP.

I am using

- List item
- Window 7 64-bit version
- MS Visual C++ 2010
- The solution contains several sub-projects which deliver libary as output separately.

If anyone can help, I'll be very thankful.

Comment: When you say `MS Visio` do you mean `MS Visual Studio`?

Comment: Try using additional `/t:Rebuild` switch in msbuild command line

Comment: - Sorry, it was a tip error. I meant MS Visual Studio, not the drawing program Visio. - I add this switch, it works, but it take too much time if I let the whole solution recompile. Also I tried:C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe C:\example.sln  /p:Configuration /t:MySubProject:Rebuild. Still the same whole solution will be recompiled. Probably since "MySubProject" is my "output" project.

Comment: You can use just you project instead of `C:\example.sln`

Comment: I get the error: 
MSBUILD : error MSB4192: The project file "C:\example.vcproj" is in the ".vcproj" or ".dsp" file format, which MSBuild cannot build directly

Answer (score 1):

You can build your project by calling Visual Studio 2010 from the command line. To build without opening Visual Studio, call "devenv.com" (command-line-friendly Visual Studio executable) to build the project. More info regarding devenv command line usage can be [found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Customize the following command and run it from the command prompt to build your project:

```
"%VS100COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\devenv.com" "full-path-to-solution" /Rebuild "desired-configuration" /Project "full-path-to-project"
```

Comment: I can't find this "devenv.com" in the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE" folder. Is it a executable file, e.g. ".exe"?

Comment: you can also call `devenv.exe`, which should be in the Common7\IDE\ folder.